# If statement continuing outside include?

Tags: php, include, if-statement

I've got an index.php page, and a lot of includes on it. How can I make an if statement from the first include continue to the last include, without getting an Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You can however put the things inside the if statement in its own file and include it inside the if statement like this:

```
if(...) {
   include 'file1.php';
}
```